# Displaying the occurrences in a Histogram with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, histogram

dear StackOverflow community. I have been working on tkinter and simple python libraries recently. Got an idea of first, randomly getting 1000 letters, and after finding their occurrences, displaying the answers in a histogram by using tkinter. I have passed the first two steps, and reached the tkinter histogram.

This is what I have done so far:

```
import string
import random
from collections import Counter


a = []
for i in range(1001):
    lower_upper_alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
    random_letter = random.choice(lower_upper_alphabet)
    a.append(random_letter)

print(Counter(a))
```

I just need to display the result, which are in dictionaries, for example as in this picture:
[image: The Histogram Sample]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bar` method of `Matplotlib` was designed for this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cnt = Counter(a)
plt.bar(cnt.keys(), cnt.values(), align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xlabel('Letters')
plt.ylabel('Amounts')
plt.show()
```

As you can see, input of `plt.bar`is letters for `x` axis and their amounts for `y` axis.

#### Output:

[image]

#### Note:

You can use `plt.savefig('letters.png')` command before `plt.show()` which allows to save your image.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Really, appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome. Now, you can see I managed to do this in `matplotlib`. Do you still need to embed this in Tkinter canvas?

Comment: You can do `plt.bar(cnt.keys(), cnt.values(), align='center', alpha=0.5)` instead.

Comment: Thanks, for sure. I mixed types while scripting and these got unaccesable for some strange reason before; edited.

Answer (score 1):

**#Step 1:-**
You can convert the dictionary to a Dataframe for that you can refer to documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

**#Step 2:-**
Plot the data frame as histogram

**#Step 3:-**
Embed matplotlib graph in tkinter canvas (assuming you know how to do that baised on the output you have shown above)